# Run a function right after serving a file with web.FileResponse in aiohttp.server

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm building a file sharing web app and there are some features that I want to add that have to do with creating files and directories dynamically and serving the content temporarily until the request fully ends

I've read about the StreamResponse and Response classes in the documentation and the FileResponse class in the source code, and the only thing that I found that might be relevant was the 'task' argument for StreamResponse, but it's not very clear how to use it

I know it's an asyncio Task but does it have to be created before returning the response?

Does it run in an asyncio gather at the end of the response?

Am I even looking at the right place?

Answer (score 1):

Following [the example in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#creating-tasks), here is a function for doing this.

```
background_tasks = set()
def do_in_background (result_of_async_call):
    task = asyncio.create_task(result_of_async_call)
    background_tasks.add(task)
    task.add_done_callback(background_tasks.discard)
```

And now instead of:

```
await foo(bar)
```

you have

```
do_in_background(foo(bar))
```

What is actually going on here?

`asyncio` has an event scheduler. It is constantly doing things. Checking for incoming requests, processing requests, and so on. Tasks are the things that it will do. But the event scheduler only keeps a [weakref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html) to its tasks. If they are not referred to from anywhere else, they disappear.

The aiohttp server keeps a strong reference to the actual web request until it is responded to. And then drops it. So if you simply create a task, it stops running when the file is served. As you probably discovered. So we keep a strong reference in the `set` of `background_tasks`. This will keep the task alive as a thing until the task completes, the callback is called, and the reference is destroyed.

The result is that you can now schedule async work to run in the background after the web request is completed.

---

This is for the follow-up question.

Assuming that you're on Python 3.11 or greater, I would recommend that you:

```
async def handle(request):
    tg = asyncio.TaskGroup()
    ...
    name = request.match_info.get('name', "Anonymous")
    ...
    tg.create_task(some_coro(...))
    tg.create_task(another_coro(...))
    ...
    cancel_task = tg.create_task(asyncio.sleep(100))
    cancel_task.cancel() # Will cancel the whole task group.
    async with tg:
        pass # Will wait for the group to actually finish cancelling.
    return web.Response(text=text)
```

Comment: This will be useful for other things but i'm not exactly interested in keeping the task alive

Comment: I'm not interested in running a task beyond the request. But if I create one inside a request, does the task gets an asyncio.CancelledError when the request ends ?

Comment: @カルロサグ No. It just gets garbage collected. You have to arrange to cancel it yourself if you want that.

Comment: But in order to cancel it I first have to detect wether the FileResponse or the whole request itself has ended. How Do I do that?

Comment: @カルロサグ I offered a solution for Python 3.11+.

Comment: That solution does not work for me: the task is ending before delivering the response

Comment: Imagine the following scenario: You send a request to compress an entire directory, the directory gets compressed and the TAR.XZ file is sent back to the client and then deleted immediately. You gave the suggestion of using tasks, but the only way I thought about doing this with a task was cancelling the task AFTER the response is sent, not BEFORE, and upon the cancellation of the task, raise the asyncio.CancelledError and run the deletion of the file in the finally part of the try/except block of the task

Comment: Just to clarify: delete immediately on the server, the file gets immediately deleted on the server right after being sent completely to the client

Comment: @カルロサグ Just modify https://gist.github.com/buxx/d0a749b6673a18a90b47464b79254124 to your needs. Create the file, set the content-type to `application/x-xz`, read in a loop, delete the file, then call wait `response.write_eof()`.

Comment: I might do something with it, thanks for the help @btilly

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve this problem by modifying aiohttp's source code directly

The file I edited is web_fileresponse.py

What I did is I added an aditional variable to the FileResponse class, I named it 'delete_file_after_sending', a bool. Then in the _sendfile() method before returning the writer I added this:

```
if self.delete_file_after_sending:
    self._path.unlink()
```

This will delete the path that was given to the FileResponse

And then at my code I tested a large file like this:

```
from pathlib import Path
from aiohttp import web

...

async def download_test(request):

    ...

    test_file=Path("./some-big-movie.mkv")
    content_disposition=f"attachment; filename=\"{test_file.name}\""

    return web.FileResponse(
        path=fse_serverside,
        headers={
            "content-disposition":content_disposition,
            "content-length":f"{test_file.stat().st_size}"
        },
        chunk_size=1048576,
        delete_file_after_sending=True,
    )

...
```

And It works as intended: The large file is sent to the client correctly, and it is deleted immediately on the server's side

I tested this on a local network using a different device as the client to my machine. There are some other tests that I need to do of course, like, for example, cancelling the download, test it on a VPS, etc...